# What if I override Application and set multiDexEnabled to 'true'?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

This question is based just out of curiousity. I've been playing around with `MultiDexApplication` and the whole multi-dex stuff. It turns out, I don't really need it in my app. I've already reverted from `MultiDexApplication` to `Application` for overriding my app class.

Just for the sake of curiousity, I tried two things:

1. **Override `Application` in the app class but set `multiDexEnabled` to *true*.** In this case, nothing happened in the app, it seems to be running fine. Would there be a problem in a case I'm not foreseeing?
2. **Override `MultiDexApplication` in the app class but set `multiDexEnabled` to *false*.** I'm not able to find the class `MultiDexApplication` in this case. Enabling `multiDexEnabled` again made the class available. Why can one not extend `MultiDexApplication` without wanting to `multiDexEnabled`?

Again, this question is just for the sake of curiosity. Excuse me if it was an unnecessary read for you.

Comment: multiDexEnabled true is a build-time configuration while MultiDexApplication is for run-time support of multiple dex files on pre lollipop devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your device is running at least Android 5. Art supports multi dexing natively, so you don't anything there. Run it on a device with an older version of Android. It will crash
  2.

> Override MultiDexApplication in the app class but set minifyEnabled to
>   false.

<s>`minifyEnabled` is for Proguard. It is not related with Multidex</s>. Also, 
multiDexEnabled won't prevent you to extend `MultiDexApplication` as well. If you had this problem, then it is probably related to something else.

> Why can one not extend MultiDexApplication without wanting to
>   multiDexEnabled?

Why would you use something that you don't want/need? `MultiDexApplication` allows you to load/handle more than one `dex` file. If one is enough for your app, why bother in the first place?

Comment: My bad there. I meant `multiDexEnabled` where I wrote `minifyEnabled`. Edited my question.

Comment: I doubt there being something else behind my inability to extend `MultiDexApplication` as the only thing that changed between it showing up in suggestions and not was that I set `multiDexEnabled` to false and synced my project.

Also, I understand that what I'm trying to do is completely unnecessary. I am, I repeat, doing this just for the sake of curiousity.

Comment: *I doubt there being something else behind my inability to extend MultiDexApplication as the only thing that changed between it showing up in suggestions and not was that I set multiDexEnabled*. I tried the same thing and I was able to extend it. I am not sure what is wrong in your set up. *Also, I understand that what I'm trying to do is completely unnecessary. I am, I repeat, doing this just for the sake of curiousity. * That's fine :)

Comment: But I've repeated this exercise back and forth 3-4 times now. As soon as I set `multiDexEnabled` to 'true' and sync, it shows up in suggestions. Could it be because I haven't imported a library containing the package `android.support.multidex` explicitly? I've seen examples that seemed to import some library for MultiDex.

Comment: usually the ide takes care of the import, but yes it could be. Do you have the dependency in your gradle tho?

Comment: Nope, I don't. But I never did even when I was using `MultiDexApplication`. Have released two versions of my app with it.

Comment: the dependency is necessary (`compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116697/discussion-between-slashg-and-blackbelt).